Assistance Needed: Extracting Full Modification History from List Items
I need to download the entire history of modifications for the items on my list to identify when the status changed and to obtain those dates for new columns in a table.
I am using this code found by Nadeem Yousuf-AIS. However, the issue is that the export does not yield the desired information. It's likely due to the column names, but despite trying several methods, I haven't been able to obtain the information.
I would appreciate your assistance.
Thank you,
Estes el codigo que ha fucinoado:
# ******* Variables Section ******************
#Define these variables
$WebURL="http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/Sales/"
$ListName ="Invoice"
$ReportFile = "D:\Invoice_VersionHistory.csv"
# *********************************************

#delete file if exists
If (Test-Path $ReportFile)
 {
 Remove-Item $ReportFile
 }

#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

 #Check if list exists
 if($List -ne $null)
 {
  #Get all list items
  $ItemsColl = $List.Items

  #Write Report Header
  Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value "Item ID, Version Lable, Created by, Created at, Title"

  #Loop through each item
  foreach ($item in $ItemsColl)
  {
   #Iterate each version
      foreach($version in $item.Versions)
       {
    #Get the version content
    $VersionData = "$($item.id), $($version.VersionLabel), $($version.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName), $($version.Created), $($version['Title'])"
    #Write to report
    Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value $VersionData
   }
  }
 }
Write-Host "Version history has been exported successfully!"


This code is another one with the same behaviour:

# Define the site and list
$siteUrl = "https://ii.sharepoint.com/sites/ifs-igo-requests"
$listName = "DA Ops Requests"

# Connect to the site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -UseWebLogin

# Get the list items using the list name and select the first 10 items in descending order by ID
$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -PageSize 1000 | Sort-Object -Property ID -Descending | Select-Object -First 10

# Initialize an array to hold the version history
$versionHistory = @()

# Initialize progress bar
$totalItems = $listItems.Count
$currentItem = 0

# Loop through each list item
foreach ($item in $listItems) {
    # Update progress bar
    $currentItem++
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Items" -Status "Processing item $currentItem of $totalItems" -PercentComplete (($currentItem / $totalItems) * 100)

    # Get the version history of the item
    $versions = Get-PnPListItemVersion -List $listName -Identity $item.Id

    # Loop through each version and add it to the array
    foreach ($version in $versions) {
        $versionHistory += [PSCustomObject]@{
            ItemID = $item.Id
            Title = $item["Title"]
            VersionLabel = $version.VersionLabel
            Modified = $version.Modified
            ModifiedBy = $version.ModifiedBy
            FieldChanges = $version.FieldValues
        }
    }
}

# Export the version history to a CSV file
$versionHistory | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\jal\Downloads\Pending Transcript\VersionHistory.csv" -NoTypeInformation


Output:


